# Google Cloud loggin doesn't log all messages

Tags: python-3.x, google-app-engine, google-cloud-logging

I have a small program running on google app engine, I am using this function to write logs, in python 3.7:

```
def write_entry(text="", severity="", log_dict={}):
  """Writes log entries to the given logger."""
  logging_client = logging.Client()

  auth_data = auth().data_values
  logger = logging_client.logger(auth_data['LOGGER_NAME'])

  if not log_dict:
    # Simple text log with severity.
    logger.log_text(text, severity=severity)

  if log_dict:
    logger.log_struct(log_dict)
```

I've tested the program using this function from localhost with ngrok and the logs were collected.
After I've uploaded the code to app engine it only writes the first log, no other logs is collected. Does it need some permission in google app engine to work properly?

Comment: Are you using Standard or Flexible Environment?

Comment: I am using Standard

Comment: From what I can see, you are trying to write structured logs. Does the same thing happen when writing [standard logs](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/samples/logging-stdlogging)?